# Chrome inspect devices not showing device

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, android-debug

Sometimes when opening the Google Chrome inspect devices tab ( chrome://inspect/#devices ) the connected device is not showing, even though the debug is enabled in the device and the drivers are properly installed.

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what the problem could be, but I found it useful to restart the `adb server`:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

And you can then check that your device is listed by running

```
adb devices
```